# transfer paths with white spaces by unix pipe

Tags: unix, pipe

I'm trying to pass paths with white spaces using pipe. however, the target command expect the input paths to be quoted. how can it be done ?

here's my attempt (just an example to emphasis the problem) :

```
find /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ | xargs egrep -v goog
```

egrep get the paths split due to the white space

```
egrep: /Applications/Google: No such file or directory
egrep: Chrome.app/: No such file or directory
```

any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page for xargs:

> The  command line for command is built up until it reaches a system-de‐
>   fined limit (unless the -n and -L options  are  used).   The  specified
>   command  will  be invoked as many times as necessary to use up the list
>   of input items.  In general, there will be many  fewer  invocations  of
>   command  than  there  were items in the input.  This will normally have
>   significant performance benefits.  Some commands can usefully  be  exe‐
>   cuted in parallel too; see the -P option.
>
> Because  Unix  filenames  can contain blanks and newlines, this default
>   behaviour is often problematic; filenames containing blanks and/or new‐
>   lines  are  incorrectly  processed by xargs.  In these situations it is
>   better to use the -0 option, which prevents such problems.   When using
>   this option you will need to ensure that the program which produces the
>   input for xargs also uses a null character as  a  separator.   If  that
>   program is GNU find for example, the -print0 option does this for you.

Try `find /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ -print0 | xargs -0 egrep -v goog`.